# JQuery Mobile - is there a way to turn off AJAX for the whole page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I am converting an existing ASP.NET website to use jQuery Mobile controls. The first thing I did was replace the Login.aspx with the new Masterpage and mobile controls. However, now after the login occurs, in the code-behind, there is a Response.Redirect to Default.aspx. When that occurs, a javascript error occurs and the whole page dumps and fails to load.

My assumption is that the mechnanism(s) in jQuery mobile that try to AJAX everything are not playing nicely with scripts that MS.NET is producing. So I want jQuery to ignore the redirect and not AJAXify it.

The problem is, all the solutions I see have to do with adding code to the anchor tag, but I'm redirecting from behind, not using an anchor tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the attribute `data-ajax="false"` to the `<form>` tag on the page. That way when the login form is submitted, jQuery Mobile won't try to update the page using AJAX.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using jQuery mobile then you can use following code to disable ajax through the page.

```
<script>
   $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the JQueryMobile documentation [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/api/globalconfig.html)

The easiest way would be to have this , `ajaxFormsEnabled :false`

Comment: I wouldn't use this. The `ajaxFormsEnabled` option was deprecated and has been removed as of Beta 1. See http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/06/20/jquery-mobile-beta-1-released/ and https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/8929ac33b9f73d0a8cb5d3476682f8c3d2423830

Comment: My bad, I only used it on Alphas so didnt know about the changes in Beta. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: FWIW, You can still use the `ajaxEnabled` option.