# ASP.NET Response.Redirect with jQuery Mobile - Url hashing

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I have a standard forms auth ASP.NET application.  My Registration and Login page are in the same .aspx file with 2 jQuery Mobile pages.  If I postback my ASP.NET page, such as the user fails to login correctly...etc  The Url hash starts appending to itself over and over.

Example Url:
**http://localhost:56644/Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx%3fbla%3dtest&bla=test#Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx%3fbla%3dtest&bla=test**

Once my user is authenticated I want to Redirect to the ReturnUrl without all the hash information or find a way for the url to remain during postbacks?

**Markup:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="register">
    <div data-role="content" data-scroll="true" data-theme="b" class="Content">
        ......  
        <a href='#login'>Login</a               
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="login">
    <div data-role="content" data-scroll="true" data-theme="b" class="Content">
        .....                             
        <a href='#register' >Registered Yet?</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code-behind on Register.aspx:**

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (LoggedIn)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("blabla", true); 
        //Note: Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] = "/Default.aspx?bla=test";
        Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);

    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697959/jquery-mobile-is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-ajax-for-the-whole-page

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post but having experienced the same issue I'll post the solution I have worked out - it is a bit rough but it may help someone or be improved. Moreover it is in ASP.NET MVC 4 - not sure how to migrate the same code to aspx

What I am basically doing is capturing the RedirectTo URL and using it to provide as `data-url` attribute of the LogOn form tag.
In other terms, in MVC 4:

1. I create a copy of the LogOn.csthml as LogOn.Mobile.cshtml
2. in LogOn.Mobile.cshtml I add the following:
   :

   ```
    @{
    string landPage = Request.Url.Query.Length>11?
   Request.Url.Query.Substring(11):"";//very rough, to be improved. 
      // Here I am clipping the RedirectTo prefix of the Query
    }
   //replaces the boilerplate @using (Html.BeginForm())
   @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", FormMethod.Post, 
     new { @data_url = landPage}))
   ```

This should enough to make it work

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (LoggedIn)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("blabla", true); 
        //Note: Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] = "/Default.aspx?bla=test";

         // This will get only the first instance of ReturnUrl
         var url = Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Substring(
                Request.Url.PathAndQuery.IndexOf("ReturnUrl=") + ("ReturnUrl=").Length);

        Response.Redirect(url);

    }
}
```

Comment: See my comment in the code, the url is always correct, the jQuery Mobile framework changes the browser url as noted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Mobile is designed to only have one page and use #page to load via ajax the page you want to go to.

from what i can see its trying to append its method of indicating the page our on thus the #Register.aspx its adding to the end.

My solution for this problem was to use usercontrols for the different mobile sections of my site and i used ajax for anything that would have normally been a postback.